# "Growl Popup" for Media Player 12?

Tags: windows-media-player

don't know how it's really called. i'm looking for a way to display a short message above the try after a new song begins to play. something like (or with?) growl fpr windows?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will work for you:

**[Snarl](http://fullphat.net/index.php)** is a notification system for Windows. It provides a standard, simple way for applications to notify the user of events.

Comment: I'm using Snarl for other apps but I could not find a way to have WMP display the track info in Snarl.

Comment: hence the 'maybe', i'm not using the software but i remember it being advertised somewhere as 'Growl for Windows'.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a Windows Media Player plug-in.

To do this, you would use the Windows Media Player SDK:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393415(VS.85).aspx
```

The core SDK requires that you code in C++, however using this project you could use C# in the future though currently it only supports visualizations:

```
http://wmppluginsnet.codeplex.com/
```

Comment: can't believe that nobody wrote a plugin like that for now. but can't a plugin like that. looks like I#ll have do write it by myself. time to get around c++. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Install the "Windows Media Player GNTP Plugin", then you can use [Snarl](http://getsnarl.info/) to show notifications:

http://wmpgntp.codeplex.com

> WMP-GNTP allows Windows Media Player to tell Growl for Windows when a song has changed, so you'll no longer have to open Windows Media Player to tell when a song has changed.

Comment: (Welcome to Super User! I'm not on Windows, but WMP-GNTP seems fine. However, [your original answer](http://superuser.com/posts/828098/revisions) was not providing much detail, and linking to an executable file is not too nice either, hence the downvote I guess. I've edited; maybe the downvoter will click the downvote again to remove it.)